# I use gson to serialize a java object, and set LongSerializationPolicy is LongSerializationPolicy.STRING, but I can't understand the result

Tags: java, gson

I use gson to serialize a java object, and set LongSerializationPolicy.STRING to serialize Long field. Like this:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .setLongSerializationPolicy(LongSerializationPolicy.STRING)
        .create();

Map<String, Long> resultMap = Maps.newHashMap();
resultMap.put("id", 123456789L);

JsonObject dataObj = new JsonObject();
dataObj,addProperty("id", 123456789L);

System.out.println(gson.toJson(resultMap));
System.out.println(gson.toJson(dataObj));
```

and the result is:

```
{"id":"123456789"}
{"id":123456789}
```

Why the result is different? The two results I expect are `{"id":"123456789L"}`

Answer (score 0):

I believe that's because `JsonObject` adds your values as `Map<String,JsonValue>` and `JsonValue` extends `Object`, so when serializing whatever you put as your value will be parsed as a string.